# Set dynamic Ids for @spring.formSingleSelect fields in FTL

Tags: spring, freemarker

I have a FTL page which contains multiple popups. Each popup contains the following single select dropdown.

```
<@spring.formSingleSelect "account.name" accountMap "class='nab'">
```

I want to set dynamic ids for each select dropdown appending the account number. I tried the following which is not working.

```
<@spring.formSingleSelect "account.name" accountMap "class='nab' id='select_{accountNumber}'">
```

Any suggestion on this?

Comment: In case `accountNumber` is a variable accessible for FreeMarker, what if  you write `id='select_${accountNumber}'` (note the `$`)?

Comment: I tried that as well.  <@spring.formSingleSelect "account.name" accountMap "class='nab' id='select_${accountNumber}'">  . But did not work. When I verifed the HTML , I could see <select id="name" > instead of the dynamic Id

Answer (score 1):

You might use this "official" suggested approach through the **@spring.bind** tag (in that case you see the 'input text' but I hope you can do the same with select.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch16s04.html

```
 <!-- freemarker macros have to be imported into a namespace.  We 
strongly
recommend sticking to 'spring' -->
<#import "spring.ftl" as spring />
<html>
...
<form action="" method="POST">
  Name: 
  <@spring.bind "command.name" /> 
  <input type="text" 
    name="${spring.status.expression}" 
    id="your_customized_id"
    value="${spring.status.value?default("")}" /><br>
  <#list spring.status.errorMessages as error> <b>${error}</b> <br> 
</#list>
  <br>
  ... 
  <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
...
</html>
```